# UnityとPhoton PUNを使用したVRマルチプレイヤーゲームでの個別の指の動きの同期に関する問題

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityでPhoton PUNを使用してMeta Quest向けのVRマルチプレイヤーゲームを開発しています。ゲームでは、個々の指の動きが重要な詳細な手のアニメーションを特徴としています。しかし、リモートプレイヤーにおいて人差し指と親指の動きが正確に複製されていない、という同期の問題に直面しています。

現在の実装では、NetworkPlayer スクリプトがOculusコントローラーからの入力に基づいて手のアニメーションを更新しています。InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.LeftHand) および InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.RightHand) を使用して手の入力を取得し、それに応じてアニメーターパラメータ（Flex および Pinch）を更新しています。

問題は、ローカルプレイヤーの手のアニメーション（人差し指と親指の動きを含む）は完全に機能しているのに対し、これら特定の指の動きがリモートプレイヤーのアバターで同期されていないことです。彼らは人差し指と親指が常に伸ばされた状態で表示され、トリガーボタンの検出や同期の問題があることを示唆しています。

手のモデルにはOculus Integrationから導入された \Assets\Oculus\SampleFramework\Core\CustomHands\CustomHandLeft.prefab を使用しています。

以下は、NetworkPlayer スクリプトからの関連するコードのスニペットです：

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;
using Unity.XR.CoreUtils;

public class NetworkPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform head;
    public Transform leftHand;
    public Transform rightHand;

    public Animator leftHandAnimator;
    public Animator rightHandAnimator;
    private PhotonView photonView;

    private Transform headRig;
    private Transform leftHandRig;
    private Transform rightHandRig;

    void Start()
    {
        photonView = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        XROrigin rig = FindObjectOfType<XROrigin>();
        headRig = rig.transform.Find("Camera Offset/Main Camera");
        leftHandRig = rig.transform.Find("Camera Offset/LeftHand Controller");
        rightHandRig = rig.transform.Find("Camera Offset/RightHand Controller");

        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            foreach (var item in GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
            {
                item.enabled = item.CompareTag("Head");
            }
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            MapPosition(head, headRig);
            MapPosition(leftHand, leftHandRig);
            MapPosition(rightHand, rightHandRig);

            UpdateHandAnimation(InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.LeftHand), leftHandAnimator, true);
            UpdateHandAnimation(InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(XRNode.RightHand), rightHandAnimator, false);
        }
    }

    void UpdateHandAnimation(InputDevice targetDevice, Animator handAnimator, bool isLeftHand)
    {
        if (handAnimator == null)
            return;

        if (targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.trigger, out float flexValue))
        {
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Flex", flexValue);
        }
        else
        {
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Flex", 0);
        }

        if (targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.grip, out float pinchValue))
        {
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Pinch", pinchValue);
        }
        else
        {
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Pinch", 0);
        }

        int pose = DeterminePose(flexValue, pinchValue);
        handAnimator.SetInteger("Pose", pose);

        photonView.RPC("UpdateHandAnimationRPC", RpcTarget.Others, flexValue, pinchValue, pose, isLeftHand);
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void UpdateHandAnimationRPC(float flex, float pinch, int pose, bool isLeftHand)
    {
        Animator handAnimator = isLeftHand ? leftHandAnimator : rightHandAnimator;
        if (handAnimator != null)
        {
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Flex", flex);
            handAnimator.SetFloat("Pinch", pinch);
            handAnimator.SetInteger("Pose", pose);
        }
    }

    int DeterminePose(float flexValue, float pinchValue)
    {
        if (flexValue > 0.5f && pinchValue > 0.5f)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (flexValue > 0.5f)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if (pinchValue > 0.5f)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void MapPosition(Transform target, Transform rigTransform)
    {
        target.position = rigTransform.position;
        target.rotation = rigTransform.rotation;
    }
}
```

関連のインスペクターの中身
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ヒエラルキー
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この問題は、入力検出の処理方法やこれら特定の指の動きをネットワーク上で同期させる方法に関連している可能性があります。同様の問題に直面したことがある方、またはPhoton PUN環境でこれら個々の指の動きを正確に同期させる方法についての洞察を提供できる方はいらっしゃいませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

photonView.IsMine は、想定通りの判定となっているでしょうか？
[リファレンス](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/ja-jp/pun/current/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_view.html#a67184424cffe2daae9001e06a6192d21) によると、ローカル Player の場合、true となると説明されているので、リモートプレイヤーの場合は、動作しないのではないでしょうか？

[image: photonView.IsMine]